# Is it possible to connect to WiFi automatically by capturing QR-Code?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, wifi, qr-code

I'm newbie in iOS development(SwiftUI).

Recently, I have encountered a problem about connecting to WiFi by capturing QR-Code.
I wonder that if is there any possible solution to connect to WiFi directly by using QR-Code.
After I did a lot of research, I still cannot find any references about this issue.
There are my keywords: SwiftUI, Swift, QR-Code, Wi-Fi, iOS.

**What do I have now:**

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingScanner = false
    @State private var resultOfScanning: String = "Result will be shown here..."
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { self.isShowingScanner = true }, label: { Text("Scan Button") })
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$isShowingScanner) {
                    CodeScannerView(codeTypes: [.qr], simulatedData: "www.opgg.com", completion: self.handleScan)
            }
            Text("\(resultOfScanning)")
        }
    }

    func handleScan(result: Result<String, CodeScannerView.ScanError>) {
        self.isShowingScanner = false
        switch result {
        case .success(let code):
            let codeStr = code as! String
            self.resultOfScanning = codeStr
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Scanning failed")
        }
    }
}
```

**CodeScannerView** (Reference: An article by Paul Hudson)

**What do I wanna build:**
I want to use this App, connecting to the specific WiFi automatically by capturing QR-Code(It contains SSID & Password of WiFi).

**What is my problem:**
I cannot find a way to connect to the specific WiFi automatically by using QR-Code. It seems that no one have talked about this issue.

May someone know that how to solve the problems like above-mentioned?

Thanks for comments and answers.

Comment: I find a way to implement this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have four steps to deal with this issue.

1.Capture the QR-Code which contains the specific WiFi hotspot information(**SSID, Password, Encryption Type**).

2.Convert **JSON data** of QR-Code to **Dictionary**.

3.Get the SSID, Password and Encryption type value from before-mentioned Dictionary.

4.Use **[NEHotspotConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration)** of Apple API to set our SSID, Password and Encryption type and connect to the specific WiFi Hotspot.

*p.s. Your app needs the signing certificate to active some function of your project and Apple API.*

Let's see what have I done here:

```
func handleScan(result: Result<String, CodeScannerView.ScanError>) {
switch result {
case .success(let code):
    let data_code = code.data(using: .utf8)
    do {
        let dict_code = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data_code!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String : Any]
        let wifi_ssid = dict_code["S"] as! String
        let wifi_pwd = dict_code["P"] as! String
        let wifi_type = dict_code["T"] as! String

        let configuration = NEHotspotConfiguration.init(ssid: wifi_ssid, passphrase: wifi_pwd, isWEP: self.checkWifiType(type: wifi_type))
        configuration.joinOnce = true
        NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(configuration) {
            (error) in
            if error != nil {
                if let errorStr = error?.localizedDescription {
                    print("Error Information:\(errorStr)")
                }
                if (error?.localizedDescription == "already associated.") {
                    print("Connected!")
                } else {
                    print("No Connected!")
                }
            } else {
                print("Connected!")
            }
        }

        print("Dict_Code:\(dict_code)")
    } catch (let error) {
        print("JSONSerial... Convert Error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

case .failure(let error):
    self.connectionStatus = "Scanning failed!"
}
}
```

**After doing this, I finally can scan my own QR-Code and connect to the specific WiFi Hotspot.**